# Setting up php , but i already have Apache and MySql

Tags: php, installation

I want to start php but i'm not sure what to install. Most of the sites i visited had instructions on how too install all three( `php` , `Apache` , `MySql`) as a package. They also mentioned `phpMyAdmin`. Note that amongst these four technologies , I only know MySql . And there are so many options on the internet that I'm unsure of where to start.

So , Do i have to delete the stuff that i have got installed already ? or is there some way i can keep them and installed only php and get things working ?

I'm on windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: Does this do what you need? http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I just did this earlier today actually. XAMPP is super useful and easy to install. It has Apache, Mysql, php, phpmyadmin, a mail server and more. You might even be able to keep what you already have (especially if you change port numbers).

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I'v heard of XAMPP , it would really help if someone could confirm if installing xampp will keep what i already have.

Comment: XAMPP installs into its own directory, so you might have to change the ports XAMPP uses if you are using them for what you already have installed, but it shouldn't cause you to lose what you already have.